# python socket and vpn

Tags: python, sockets, vpn

my question is if I use a vpn and try to send a message on a python socket message, not of any protocol, will my socket traffic go through the vpn and my ip be hidden from the message receiver? I found that I can't see the traffic using wireshark because it's not of any protocol. ***THANKS FOR THE HELP!***

Comment: What do mean with "not of any protocol"? Please share some code.

Comment: If traffic will be send through the VPN depends on the destination and the setup of the VPN. In most cases with a properly setup VPN the traffic will be send through the VPN but this is not true for all setups and all destinations. If it is setup through the VPN the destination will see the IP of the IP endpoint and not your local IP address. And, this is unrelated to Python but all applications behave the same unless they specifically try to be different.

Comment: @arghol I mean I'm not sending any http/etc. protocol message just for example socket.send("hello")

Comment: @IsaacDj in what case wouldn't it?

Comment: The reason you can't see the traffic with Wireshark could be that you are looking at the wrong network interface. VPNs often use their own virtual adapter, not the physical adapter like the ethernet or wi-fi adapter.

Answer (score 1):

To establish a socket connection with a vpn is possible but...
I tried the same project and got this result:

1. To establish a socket connection in the VPN server, you need to connect your device in which you execute your code to the vpn.
2. Type in ipconfig and get the vpn's IP address and bind a socket in Python using the IP.
3. Now if you execute the project within the same pc the project works.

But if you use a different Wi-Fi connection in another pc it doesn't but why?

Here comes port forwarding:

The vpn allocates a private IP address to your computer. A private IP address can be used to communicate with devices within your LAN (modem). But if you try to connect private IP address from other network, it would fail to communicate with your pc. So, to solve this public IP address is used. Each modem (even vpn servers) have a public IP address. It is like a tool for communication of devices across any network. For example online game servers runs using public IP address. This is the reason Windows firewall pops up when you enter an online game in Windows. But even if you type the public IP the socket doesn't work.

Here comes port forwarding. Think, many devices are connected to your network or vpn server. The modem or vpn does not know which device should it transmit the message. If you port forward the private IP address and the exact port number. It now finally works!

> NOTE: Public IP's are sensitive and hackers can enter any VPN server using public IP address. So most VPN providers do not provide public IP. Only with the main VPN server you can port forward. So you need to contact the VPN service provider and request for a port forwarding to your private IP and finally program you socket and your project may work.

> NOTE: You  need a TCP/UDP protocol for a socket.

Comment: You spend an awful lot of time talking about port forwarding considering that you can’t port forward when you aren’t using any protocol. I realize that I am several years late but I don’t understand how this at all answers the question. Your note about needing a tcp/udp protocol for a socket is false.